# Programming two WKWebViews, one a transparent overlay

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview

I'm currently trying to program to WKWebViews in the app: one that acts as the main `webView`, the other that is hidden by default and acts as a transparent overlay when called to show (`loadingView`). So far, it seems as if neither are showing (or it is only showing the `loadingView`, which is hidden by default).

ViewController.swift

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, WKNavigationDelegate {

    var webView: WKWebView!
    var loadingView: WKWebView!
    @IBOutlet var textField: UITextField!

    override func loadView() {
        view = webView
        webView = WKWebView()
        webView.navigationDelegate = self
        webView.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        webView.opaque = true

        view = loadingView
        loadingView = WKWebView()
        loadingView.navigationDelegate = self
        loadingView.hidden = true
        loadingView.alpha = 0.5
        loadingView.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()

        UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarStyle = .Default
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        let url = NSURL(string: "about:blank")!
        webView.loadRequest(NSURLRequest(URL: url))
        webView.allowsBackForwardNavigationGestures = true

        let loadingURL = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("LoaderPhone", withExtension:"html")!
        self.loadingView.loadRequest(NSURLRequest(URL: loadingURL))

        // Notification observer for textField
        self.textField.addTarget(self, action: "textFieldDidUpdate:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.EditingChanged)
    }

    func textFieldDidUpdate(textField: UITextField) {
        if (textField.text!.rangeOfCharacterFromSet(NSCharacterSet.whitespaceCharacterSet()) != nil) {
            guard
                let text = textField.text,
                query = text.stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters(.URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet()),
                url = NSURL(string: "https://google.com/#q=\(query)")
                else { return }
            loadingView.hidden = true
            webView.loadRequest(NSURLRequest(URL: url))

        } else {
            // Validate URL
            NSURL.validateUrl(textField.text, completion: { (success, urlString, error) -> Void in
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
                    if (success) {
                        self.loadingView.hidden = true
                        let request = NSURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: urlString!)!)
                        print(urlString!)
                        self.webView.loadRequest(request)
                    } else {
                        self.webView.stopLoading()
                        self.loadingView.hidden = false
                        print("View is hidden")
                    }
                })
            })
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have instantiated the web views but you have not added them to your view.

You need to add:

```
view.addSubview(webView)
view.addSubview(loadingView)
```

You also need to create your web view with:

```
webView = WKWebView(frame: view.bounds, configuration: webViewConfig)
```

Comment: Hi @Onato, still doesn't seem to be working. Just getting a black screen. [(Project)](https://github.com/revblaze/WiBlaze)

Comment: You need to set the frame otherwise the web view has a size of 0x0.